# Android - DialogFragment in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to implement a dialog fragment within a fragment class. Basically I have set an action listener on a button within the fragment class that button will open a dialog where the user will input two EdiText fields then press ok, it will pass that user input towards SQLite database.

How can I implement this? What do I have to inflate? I am new to working with fragments

```
ublic class tsk extends Fragment {


DatabaseHelper help;
Button add;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false);
    add = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addbtn);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onClick works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            //LayoutInflater inflater= getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            //this is what I did to added the layout to the alert dialog
            final EditText titleInput=(EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title);
            final EditText bodyInput=(EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.dialog_body);

        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AlertDialog.Builder has a setPositiveButton (also has negative and neutral) method with a listener interface implementation.

```
   new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Grab edit text content and process it here     
        }
    });
```

There are a few things in the API documents that allow for customisation.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html